# Adding 2 columns together when criteria is met in another column using query

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

In this sheet[¹](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bZIuXBSy36zEjlGfBKGevYDGxluvLALdbHVdikA5UcU/edit?usp=sharing) ,I need to add 2 columns J & K from the archive tab when column G contains pick.

The formula I have tried is this:

Figures!D7:

```
=QUERY(Archive!$A:$Y,"SELECT SUM(J)+ SUM(K) where G contains 'Pick'",0)
```

But I get `#value` error on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QUERY seems to treat the duration values in columns J & K as text

I would use a FILTER instead:

`=SUM(FILTER(Archive!$J:$K,IFERROR(FIND("Pick",Archive!$G:$G),0)))`

You also need to remove the *,1* from the end of your QUERY in cell A1 of the Archive sheet.  It causes row 1 to be treated as a text-format header row.